# Assigning ordinal numeral to sequence without post-decrement in scala

Tags: scala

As I'm new to scala I google many things and find good answers in most cases. But I couldn't find an answer to this specific question as googling "post-decrement in scala" only brings dontcha-use-post-decrement-in-scala-because-its-a-functional-language-answers to the top.

So, I really want to know what's the functional way of doing the following:

```
object A {
  val list = List("a", "b", "c")
  val map = {
    var ord = list.size
    Map(list map { x => (x, { val res = ord; ord -= 1; res } ) } : _* )
  }
}

class Test extends org.scalatest.FunSuite {
  test("") {
    println(A.map) // Map(a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1)
  }
}
```

It's basically creating a map from a given list and assigning decreasing ordinal numerals to each element of the list (real code is of course more complex than this minimal example).

I'm especially unhappy with `var ord = ...` (mutable) and `{ val res = ord; ord -= 1; res }` (post-decrement) parts :/ Is there another (prettier) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would require reversing the list and then you can use `zipWithIndex`:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

List("a", "b", "c")
  .reverse
  .zipWithIndex
  .toMap

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(c -> 0, b -> 1, a -> 2)
```

If you don't mind the allocations of the extra collections, you can remove `view`.

Comment: The second `reverse`is unnecessary, given the `toMap`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I agree, but I wanted the example to print it the way OP wanted to see it. Perhaps I should remove it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I'm aware of maps not being ordered ;)

Comment: Map's print order is just an implementation artifact. I think it's misleading to apparently say one can reliably define the order

Comment: @Alex Ok then :) Updated.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Yeah, it was a bad idea anyway, one could read this and mistakenly think there is something order related in the map. Updated.

Comment: Looks good so far but I'm needing it with `c -> 1, b -> 2, a -> 3` for some calculation later on. Is there a way incrementing it within zipWithIndex?

Comment: @Alex `zipWithIndex` index starts at `0`, you'll either need to manually `zip` or add an additional: `.map(t => (t._1, t._2 + 1)` after `zipWithIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

[zip](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):List[(A,B)]) is helpful for this,

```
list.reverse.zip(1 to list.size + 1).toMap
```

Comment: You don't need the `+ 1`

Answer (score 1):

And yet another variant

```
list.zip(list.size to 1 by -1).toMap
```

Similar in performance to the `.reverse.zipWithIndex`, because both `reverse` and `size` are O(N)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this:

```
 val list = List("a","b","c")
 list.map ( elem => (elem, list.size - list.indexOf(elem))).toMap
```

It will give you the result like this:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 2, c -> 1)
```

Comment: Will fail if two elements have the same value. Also, `indexOf` is O(N) so this is gratuitously slow.

Comment: Although to be fair it's not clear what the OP wants if two elements have the same value...

Comment: I know but as per your question i gave the solution but You want to create a map with same key multiple times ?

Comment: try this                     for (i <- list.size to 1 by -1) yield (list(list.size - i),i)                                           you will get   scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(String, Int)] = Vector((a,4), (b,3), (c,2), (a,1))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list.toIterator.zip(Iterator.iterate(list.size){_-1}).toMap
```